# Prove $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, (n|105 \wedge n|70) \implies 5|n$

Tags: proof-writing

I know the definition of divides into is $$a|b \equiv \exists a\in\mathbb{Z}, b = ac$$ however I'm not sure how to manipulate this to prove $$\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, (n|105 \wedge n|70) \implies 5|n$$

Any help to lead me in the right way would be appreciated! I'm new to proofs so please explain any steps I could take!

Comment: Woops, would n = 1 be a counter example?

Comment: Yes.  Yes it would.  $n=7$ is also.  Further $a\mid b$ if and only if $\exists \color{red}{c}\in\Bbb Z$ such that $b=ac$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that would also be false using $n=7$ or $n=35$ as counterexamples.

Comment: @AndréNicolas $5$ doesn't have all that many divisors...

Comment: Forgot about $7$.

Answer (score 1):

$n=1$ and $n=7$ are counterexamples.

Since $\gcd(105,70)=35$, $1,5,7$, and $35$ can be candidates of $n$, but $1$ and $7$ are not multiple of $5$.